# Opacidade de imagens C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics

Bom dia, me deparei com um problema em minha aplicação *Windows Form C#*, estou tentando aplicar uma imagem com baixa **opacidade(transparência)** de background para meu `panel1`, porém a imagem quando inserida fica com 100% de opacidade, dando conflito com o que esta por cima do background. Tentei primeiramente apenas colocar a imagem como background do panel e não funcionou. Como trabalhando com Bitmaps eu consigo usar fundo transparente pensei que pudesse ser a solução do problema, porém sem sucesso também. Algo pode ser feito para que a imagem não perca a **transparência**?

```
Bitmap config;

private void FormConfig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    config = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\...\background_config.png"); //imagem quase transparente
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(config, new Point(0, 0));
}
```

Comment: Felipe, bom dia! Não estou com código na mão para testar a classe Bitmap, mas não tem um overload nela que informa o tipo de extensão ou coisa do tipo quando vai carregar a imagem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo encontrado em [Change Opacity of Image in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/201129/Change-Opacity-of-Image-in-C):

```
/// <summary>  
/// method for changing the opacity of an image  
/// </summary>  
/// <param name="image">image to set opacity on</param>  
/// <param name="opacity">percentage of opacity</param>  
/// <returns></returns>  
public Image SetImageOpacity(Image image, float opacity)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        //create a Bitmap the size of the image provided  
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);  

        //create a graphics object from the image  
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {  

            //create a color matrix object  
            ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();      

            //set the opacity  
            matrix.Matrix33 = opacity;  

            //create image attributes  
            ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();      

            //set the color(opacity) of the image  
            attributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);    

            //now draw the image  
            gfx.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
        }
        return bmp;  
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)  
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

Questão também discutida no **SOen** no tópico [Changing the Opacity of a Bitmap image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779027/changing-the-opacity-of-a-bitmap-image).